# Do we need to delete the constraints when we mark some table columns as unused?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

There are a couple of columns that have constraints on them. I am setting these columns to unused. Should I be dropping the constraints?

Comment: What do you mean b setting them as unused? Ifthey are being dropped, the constraints are automatically removed.

Comment: @rontornambe: there is a DDL command to set a column to "unused": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53388

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the constraints if you want, but there's no rule saying you have to.

If you end up later dropping the columns, the constraints will be dropped automatically anyway.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Database_Administration/DBA_36.shtml#Method1Example

we can mark the columns as unused. unused is like deleting a column logically because the data is still in the table but it cannot be seen or unused.

Answer (score -1):

If the columns are not to be used, what purpose do the constraints serve?  In the interest of keeping the database lean and clean, all unneeded components (like these constraints you reference) should likely be dropped.  Without knowing exactly what you mean by "unused" I cannot comment in any greater detail.

Comment: we can mark columns as unused.unused is like deleting a column logically because the data is still in the table, but it cannot be seen or used. http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Database_Administration/DBA_36.shtml#Method1Example